# Initialization Error lines showing while start or shutdown in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, restart

From the time I have updted to ubuntu 16.04 I am getting these messages on my screen.Here is a screenshot of the error messages.
[image]
At first, I thought it would go away after

> sudo apt-get update

But nothing like that happened and I am greeted by this message each time if I restart or shutdown.So is there any fix to it because it's quite annoying?
And also if it's a bug in ubuntu 16.04 can anyone let me know what to do next.
Thanks in advance.

The output of

> cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

[image]

Comment: Does your system boot up or is stuck at the current screen?

Comment: Yes,yes it boots up but it takes quite  a time.And yes it stucks up sometimes when I shutdown my OS from the GUI.It wasn't happening in 14.04 but only happening in 16.04.Any ideas why?

Comment: Do you dual boot?

Comment: Also can you please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/812083/edit) your question with the output of `cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`.

Comment: @Raphael.No no.I haven't done dual boot.Ok I am editing the question.